# Unity3d UI - Sprite sheet slices

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet

Good day all. This is my 1st question here - so I might not be as accurate as many veterans. I am newbie in Unity and I try to make some menus and windows with Unity UI. I got this really nice sheet with all the windows / boxes / loading panels / buttons. Its  on a PSD File. And I was wondering - if there is a way to import the PSD File or I should just get them one by one / slice them and put them all in a folder.

And to be honest - any guide or nice PDF about the UI of Unity 5 will be greatly appreciated.

What i did so far is crop one of the items - and sliced it in unity - that works. Is that the way to go?

[image of the PSD file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcBwa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try check this Unity sprite editor, its very powerful since it automatically slice for you

> http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbgIA3pwpHc

Comment: I have tested the Slice Editor - for me its really powerful yes - but only slice 1 sprite - that means - 1 windows - or 1 title / button. That was the approach I was going for, To manually slice all the menus / windows / button into different png files and then using the slice editor to cut them to 9 slice sprites :) but will read more about this . Thanks for answering.